# can you put a shimano XTR M980 175mm stage power meter on a XT M785 175mm setup?

Tags: crankset

I would like a stages power meter on my set up but cant figure out if the bottom bracket sizes are correct and if even the new crank will fit at all?

Comment: I just came across this and I am in the opposite boat. I have a M785 and am considering to upgrade to the XTR M9000 (1x11) groupset. I'm wondering if I can still use my XT M785 power meter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the M785 and the M980 are hollowtech II systems and compatible. They use a compatible bottom bracket sm-bb70 and sm-bb93, which are English threaded 68/73mm.

The M980 uses the same clamping system as other Hollowtech II systems which is different to earlier xtr cranksets which required specialist tools.

The stages power meter comes as a replacement crank arm with the meter built in, so while this set up would work for aesthetic purposes wouldn't it be better to get the m785 meter?